Error connecting to Postgres database, but can connect on pgadmin
Im having this error when trying to connect to the database:

[auth][cause]: error: password authentication failed for user "user"

But i can connect to pgadmin normaly with the same credentials so I dont undertand whats going on.
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: auth_db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin_data:

.env
AUTH_DATABASE_HOST="localhost"
AUTH_DATABASE_PORT=5432
AUTH_DATABASE_NAME="auth_db"
AUTH_DATABASE_USER="user"
AUTH_DATABASE_PASSWORD="password"

pool:
import { Pool } from "pg";

export const pool = new Pool ({
    host: process.env.AUTH_DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.AUTH_DATABASE_PORT!, 10), // 10 TO MAKE IT A BASE10
    database: process.env.AUTH_DATABASE_NAME,
    user: process.env.AUTH_DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.AUTH_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
})

I tryed to connect directly to the database and got the same error:

psql -h localhost -U user -d auth_db
Password for user user:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"

But for some reason it works with pgadmin.
Im using windows and docker desktop with Hyper-V (no wsl)
idk if it helps but this are the user permissions:

"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "INSERT"
"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "SELECT"
"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "UPDATE"
"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "DELETE"
"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "TRUNCATE"
"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "REFERENCES"
"user"    "auth_db"   "public"    "users" "TRIGGER"


Did you try to use username other than “user”?

I was not able to reproduce the issue. screenshot
I was able to connect to the DB just fine. My guess is that this could be due to an issue with volume permissions. I've seen this before because of this Mounting volumes between host (MacOs BigSur) and podman VM issue.

Victor Egiazarian, i tried it and it didnt work too, thanks anyway.
oussema, I didn't quite understand the solution you sent, I'm using window btw, I apologize for not mentioning it previously. thanks anyway.

No worries. The question I shared is probably specific to mac so nevermind. Could you have a look at this possible cause?

@oussema it was that, thank you so much.

Great. I posted an answer with the solution.

Check if you have a running postgres.exe service from installing postgres on your Windows machine directly. This will prevent you from connecting to the postgres from the docker container.
See this stackoverflow question
